# Scikit-Learn/Pandas: make a prediction using a saved model based on user input

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm building a Machine Learning model using Pandas, but having a hard time applying my model to test data inputted by the user. My data is basically a dataframe with 2 columns: text and sentiment. I want to be able to predict the sentiment that the user inputs. Here's what I do:

## 1. Training/testing model

```
# reading dataset
df = pd.read_csv('dataset/dataset.tsv', sep='\t')
# splitting training/test set
test_size = 0.1
train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = model_selection.train_test_split(df['text'], df['sentiment'], test_size=test_size)

# label encode the target variable (i.e. negative = 0, positive = 1)
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
train_y = encoder.fit_transform(train_y)
valid_y = encoder.fit_transform(valid_y)

# create a count vectorizer object 
count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}')
count_vect.fit(df['text'])

# transform the training and validation data using count vectorizer object
xtrain_count = count_vect.transform(train_x)
xvalid_count = count_vect.transform(valid_x)

# function to train the model
def train_model(classifier, feature_vector_train, label, feature_vector_valid, name):
    # fit the training dataset on the classifier
    classifier.fit(feature_vector_train, label)
    # save the trained model in the "models" folder
    joblib.dump(classifier, 'models/' + name + '.pkl') 

    # predict the labels on validation dataset
    predictions = classifier.predict(feature_vector_valid)

    return metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, valid_y)

# Naive Bayes on Count Vectors
accuracy = train_model(naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(), xtrain_count, train_y, xvalid_count, 'NB-COUNT')
print("NB, Count Vectors: ", accuracy)
```

Everything works fine, accuracy of about 80%

## 2. Testing the model on user input

Then I read the saved model again, get the user input and try to make a prediction (the user input is hardcoded right now in `input_text`):

```
clf = joblib.load('models/NB-COUNT.pkl')
dataset_df = pd.read_csv('dataset/dataset.tsv', sep='\t')
input_text = 'stackoverflow is the best'  # the sentence I want to predict the sentiment for
test_df = pd.Series(data=input_text)

count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}')
count_vect.fit(dataset_df['text'])  # fit the count vectorizer again so we can extract features from test_df
features = count_vect.transform(test_df)
result = clf.predict(features)[0]
print(result)
```

But the error I get is 'dimension mismatch':

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\vdvax\iCloudDrive\Freelance\09. Arabic Sentiment Analysis\test.py", line 20, in <module>
result = clf.predict(features)[0]
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 66, in predict
jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 725, in _joint_log_likelihood
return (safe_sparse_dot(X, self.feature_log_prob_.T) +
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 135, in safe_sparse_dot
ret = a * b
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 515, in __mul__
raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to save the count vectorizer somehow so I can load it later? Because the trained model is saved to a file and then loaded in another script. Is something similar possible for the count vectorizer?

Comment: You can stack all of your preprocessors into a pipeline and pickle that just fine.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that (the code part)? I'm not familiar with pipelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the dimension mismatch error because the output of the `CountVectorizer` transformation does not match in dimensions to the expected shape in the fit estimator. This is due to the fact that you're fitting a separate `CountVectorizer` on your test data.

Scikit-learn provides a handy interface called a [`Pipeline`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) that will allow you to stack your pre-processors and estimator together in a single estimator class. You should put all of your transformers into a `Pipeline` before your estimator, and then your test data will be transformed by the pre-fit transformer classes. Here's how you could fit a pipelined version of your estimator:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# takes a list of tuples where the first arg is the step name,
# and the second is the estimator itself.
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('cvec', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}')),
    ('clf', naive_bayes.MultinomialNB())
])

# you can fit a pipeline in the same way you would any other estimator,
# and it will go sequentially through every stage
pipe.fit(train_x, train_y)

# you can produce predictions by feeding your test data into the pipe
pipe.predict(test_x)
```

Note that you don't have to create numerous copies of your data in various stages of pre-processing this way either, since the output of one stage is fed directly into the next stage.

Now, for your persistence problem. Pipelines can be persisted in the same way as other models:

```
joblib.dump(pipe, 'models/NB-COUNT.pkl')
loaded_model = joblib.load('models/NB-COUNT.pkl')
loaded_model.predict(test_df)
```